# Standard Objects in PermissionSets - Migration Retrieve Issue

Tags: permissions, migration-tool

I have a PermissionSet in a dev org. When I retrieve this PermissionSet using the migration tool, only the permissions that I have set for **Custom Objects** show. I added CRUD permissions for several **Standard Objects** but those permissions don't come down when I retrieve.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the standard objects in the CustomObject element in your package.xml file. For example:

```
<types><members>Account</members><name>CustomObject></name></types>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the product manager for profiles and permissions at salesforce.com.

There are any number of interesting behaviors that occur when migrating permissions using the metadata API. I definitely recommend checking out the following blog posting on salesforcehacker to help understand what you can and can't do when migrating permissions:

http://www.salesforcehacker.com/2013/05/dude-wheres-my-permission.html